# Docker with Angular giving error "ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'."

Tags: angular, docker, micro-frontend

Trying to create build for Angular 7 using Docker on Azuredev ops. But getting the error.

[image]

If i change the CLI version in package.json it works fine. But gives me other error in while creating build.

As the application is created using single-spa so CLI version change required changes at multiple places.

Can anyone handle this and confirm me any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This seems a common issue if you update the Angular and CLI.

The most suggested solution is to clean an resinstall your Angular and CLI.

```
npm remove webpack
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest.
```

You can refer to ["No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'" after Upgrade](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8798) and [ERROR in Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'.](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9292) for the same issue.

As you can see in the second link, this problem can be caused by a variety of different reasons, some of them are code and some are Angular and CLI version.

Comment: @latest will change my cli-version and then there would be many other version problems. Like i used RUN npm audit fix --force and i started facing issue 

Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc'.

Updating CLI version will not work as it will trap me into other multiple issues.